# Multiple Product variation type not display all price

Tags: commerce

My site has 2 product variation types: pv1, pv2.

Everything works fine, a user can add pv1 or pv2 into cart and buy them 
but the price shown is always the last selected by user.

How can I display both pv1 price and pv2 price?

Comment: This needs more information. Do you have a single product with two variations? Can you give a more concrete example?

Comment: Hi, I have a single product with two variations. The site sells tour. Example: a user want to buy a tour in USA and can choose between two variations: bus in first class and bus in second class. First and second classes are my product variations. Thanks

Comment: So you have two product displays associated with the variations, and as soon as somebody chooses an option only the price of that option is shown, and you want to be albe to show both prices at the same time?

Comment: Hi, yes exactly.